# Play!Framework: Mapping on Future creates many small tasks

Tags: scala, playframework, threadpool, future

I have an application written in Play!Framework. We map over Future a lot, and each mapping pushes tasks to the execution context. Since application is mainly asynchronous and non-blocking we use default thread config, which is equal to number of cores available in machine.

Recently I started to observe latency increase, which means each request is taking longer to finish. I was wondering if there is an overhead for mapping over Future? 
Does anyone know a good tool to investigate this sort of issue?

Thanks

Comment: Probably, but not as much as what those futures are actually doing. So.. what are they doing? Are there blocking calls inside the futures?

Comment: Its can be as simple as constructing an object to doing CPU intensive work such as parsing templates.

Comment: There are many unknowns here though for someone trying to answer this question. Are all the calls like this? How many are running concurrently vs the number of available cores?